# Teamcity server url returns 404

Tags: iis, teamcity, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-2016

I installed TeamCity on a windows server 2016 machine and I assigned the ci.mydomain.com to the serverUrl. I have IIS also on that machine that hosts my nuget server.

When I type in ci.mydomain.com it returns a 404. nuget.mydomain.com works fine

Does anyone knows why?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Server URL" in TeamCity administration settings does not affect how TeamCity server can be accessed.

You can start by opening 127.0.0.1:PORT on the server machine to check that the TeamCity is running OK, where PORT is where TeamCity is configured to run on (e.g. check \logs\teamcity-server.log file, line with "Web server ports")

If that works, make sure SERVER:PORT works from other machines, where SERVER is the machine IP and the same PORT. If you'd rather use IIS as a reverse proxy, check [related TeamCity instructions](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=74845225#HowTo...-SetUpTeamCitybehindaProxyServer).

Finally, you will need to make sure  ci.mydomain.com resolves to the IP and use due port in the URL.

Comment: ci.mydomain.com:4567 works. I want to redirect this to ci.mydomain.com (port 80).

Comment: You can run TeamCity on port 80 (requires changes in TeamCity's conf\server.xml) or you can run your nuget server and TeamCity under different paths (ci.mydomain.com/<path>): that will require TeamCity (and probably nuget server) reconfiguration. TeamCity instructions are available at the link in the answer.